# Better approach to execute procedure at Dot Net front end

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a form built in C#.Net and it has got approx 40 controls, all the controls datavalues comes from sql server database.
Which of the following is a better approach

1. Write one procedure and add all the queries for each controls in the procedure so that they execute sequentially and get result as dataset and finally loop controls and bind with each datatable.

For example:

```
connection.Open

DataSet ds = ExecuteProc("SomeProc")
control1.DataSource=ds.Tables(0)
control2.DataSource=ds.Tables(1)
control3.DataSource=ds.Tables(2)
.
.
.
.
connection.Close
```

2. Write procedure for each control and bind them, but with threading technology so that they execute parallely, but in this case for each procedure we need to open and close connections for each procedure when executed.

For example:

```
all running parallely:

connection.Open
DataSet ds = ExecuteProc("SomeProc1")
control1.DataSource=ds.Tables(0)
connection.Close

connection.Open
DataSet ds = ExecuteProc("SomeProc2")
control2.DataSource=ds.Tables(0)
connection.Close

connection.Open
DataSet ds = ExecuteProc("SomeProc3")
control3.DataSource=ds.Tables(0)
connection.Close
```

Can you help me getting the answer for the proposed methods or is there any other better approach to achieve this at faster rate?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Option 1 means you need to reflect the UI in your stored procedure. This is not a good seperation of UI from business logic. Is there actually a perforance issue, i.e. running these in serial takes far longer than running in parallel? Do you actually need a special calculation for each of these 40 data points? Is it more complicated than just 40 columns from a single row of a table?

Comment: @Yusuf Your second method is not parallel in later case also code will execute once your first connection closes.You have to give more to readers for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is the better one. *Opening/closing* a connection is a very cheap operation because of  connection pooling. *Creating* the connections is the big guy.

Comment: However querying over and over introduces latency both ways, especially 40 times...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your history, you come with a lot of preconceived notions and not enough background. "Threading" is a buzz-word for you that you want to have for the sake of having it.

If I had to choose between the two options, I'd choose the former. Introducing network latency (both ways!) can be pretty expensive, and you're talking about dozens and dozens of queries at a time.

However, I'm willing to bet you don't actually need 40 different tables. I bet you can fit all your data in one table. I mean... 40 datagrids, you don't even have room on the screen for them using a sane UI, and if you don't have a sane UI, fix it. I bet your controls are just text boxes or labels or something, so returning a single table with one cell per control is all you need.

Comment: Sorry Blindy, don't go in my background and also please please do not assume anything what you are trying to do in last para of yours. My question is straight forward, i know both have some pros and cons but need to ask from all you experienced which is better?

Comment: I thought I was clear, neither. And you're right, I shouldn't have to assume anything, you should specify in your question. Probably why it has negative votes.